# Keycloak Token Exchange Issuer

Tags: docker, keycloak

I'm trying to set up a system that allows users to use tokens that were created by an older identity solution to log in to keycloak. The way it works is I have a server that accepts these tokens, validates them and identifies the user, then impersonates the user to obtain an access/refresh token from keycloak, which it then passes back to the user.

This (mostly) works, but I'm running into a problem. The server talks to keycloak over a docker network, and the users talk to keycloak over the public internet. The "iss" field in tokens obtained this way contains the address for the keycloak server in the Docker network

e.g.

Token I get from logging in through localhost:8080

> `iss`: `https://localhost:8080/auth/`

Token I get from impersonation over docker network

> `iss`: `http://keycloak:8080`

The tokens work if I use them from inside the docker network, but outside of that, they are rejected for having an invalid issuer. In looking for answers I came across [this](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/6117) PR on the keycloak repository, but I am not clear on how to apply that solution, and can't find any example of someone doing so.

So, how exactly do I fix this problem with the `issuer` field?

EDIT: Some help from @Turing85 has gotten me closer to the solution,

by setting KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME=localhost in my docker container, the iss
from the backend is now `http://localhost:8080/auth/`, but I am still getting 401s if I try to access the "admin" endpoints, even though the token works for "/open-id" endpoints. Is it enough for the issuer hostname to be the same, or must they be identical? If they must be identical, how do I handle the fact that one endpoint uses https and the other does not?

Comment: What version of the docker image are you using? with 8.0.1, setting environment variable `KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME` should do the trick.

Comment: I'm on 11.0.0. What value should KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME be set to, the docker URL or the public one?

Comment: The one that sould appear in the `iss` claim.

Comment: That appears to have helped, but I'm still getting 401s. Is there a way to see why keycloak rejected a particular token? It passes public-key signature.

Comment: Who is rejecting the token? Keycloak or the resource server?

Comment: Keycloak is rejecting the token with 401 unauthorized. I checked the signature on the token using the public key, and the signature is valid. I'm just wondering if there is a way to give a token to keycloak, and get a detailed message on what exactly it doesn't like.

Comment: Edit `standalone.xml`, find `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">` and add the following: `<logger category="org.keycloak"><level name="DEBUG" /></logger>` you'll then see entries in `server.log` for token validation failures etc. In this case it's probably rejecting the issuer with something like `Failed to verify identity token: Invalid token issuer. Expected x but as y`